# Open custom url when user clicks push notifications in swift

Tags: php, ios, swift, firebase, push-notification

I am trying to develop an IOS / Swift application with WKWebView and Firebase Push. I want to send notifications using PHP and when a user clicks on the notification to open a custom URL in webview. default URL is

```
let url = URL(string: "https://mywebsite.com/index.php?token=\(token)")!
```

and i want to pass in this url an id like this

```
let url = URL(string: "https://client.gazduire.net/app3/index.php?token=\(token)&ntid=(id that is send with push notification, ex.:1)")!
```

My code in appdelegate.swift

```
 func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
// Print message ID.
if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
  print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
}
// Print full message.
print(userInfo)

let notificationName = Notification.Name("test")
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: notificationName, object: nil,userInfo: userInfo)

let ntid = userInfo["ntid"] as! String
print("\(ntid)")


completionHandler()
```

}

ViewController.swift

```
@objc func test() {
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let ntid = appDelegate.ntid
    let token = Messaging.messaging().fcmToken


guard let url = URL(string: "https://mywebsite.com/index.php?token=\(token ?? "")&ntid=\(ntid)")      else {
   print("Invalid URL")
   return
   }

    let request = URLRequest(url: url)
    webView.load(request)
}
```

Can i send the ntid(ntid is recived and is printed ok) from appdelegate to viewcontroller when user tap push notification?Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

In a simple way, just find your view controller in view controller's hierarchy, pass "ntid" value to stored property and call "test" method.

Comment: Can you give me a simple example? Thank you! I'am a newbie in swift language!

Answer (score 0):

first define enum as

```
enum Identifiers {
  static let viewAction = "cat1"
  static let newsCategory = "cat2"
}
```

then in your UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate

```
extension AppDelegate: UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
  func userNotificationCenter(
    _ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
    didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
    withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

    // 1
    let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo

    // 2
    if let aps = userInfo["aps"] as? [String: AnyObject],
      let newsItem = NewsItem.makeNewsItem(aps) {

      (window?.rootViewController as? UITabBarController)?.selectedIndex = 1

      // 3
      if response.actionIdentifier == Identifiers.viewAction,
        let url = URL(string: newsItem.link) {
        let safari = SFSafariViewController(url: url)
        window?.rootViewController?.present(safari, animated: true,
                                            completion: nil)
      }
    }

    // 4
    completionHandler()
  }
}
```

add category in your push service like  that

```
{
  "aps": {
    "alert": "messaga",
    "sound": "default",
    "link_url": "www.google.com",
    "category": "cat1",

  }
}
```

it will check the aps type then push view controller if category type 1 or 2.
you can add many as you want by doing this way

Comment: I have the following error: Use of unresolved identifier 'NewsItem'

Comment: NewsItem is just for the sample.use your own struct. in sample code the tabbar changes when user clicked the notification and show the news